# Laravel storage path issue

Tags: laravel

I have an issue with user avatars. I am storing them in `storage\app\public\avatars\user_id_1_username\useravatar.jpg`

In my blade view I do this:             `<img src="{{asset('storage/avatars/user_id_'.Auth::user()->id.'_'.Auth::user()->first_name.'/'.Auth::user()->avatar)}}" width="150px" alt="User Image">`

This setup works perfectly fine in localhost, but on my shared ftp hosting this does not work and I get 500 Internal Server Error. Does anyone has suggestions how could I fix that?

### EDIT

If i write `<img src="{{asset('storage/app/public/avatars/user_id_'.Auth::user()->id.'_'.Auth::user()->first_name.'/'.Auth::user()->avatar)}}" width="150px" alt="User Image">`

then it works in shared hosting but not in my localhost development. Any suggestions?

Comment: What [response] did you get when you've access the [network] tab in your [console] window?

Comment: @eeya I am getting 500 internal server error there.

Comment: If you are using [Chrome] as a browser, 

1) Right click then select [Inspect Element] or press F12.
2) Go to [Network] Tab then select the 'red highlight' image sources that produces the 500 Internal server error.

Comment: @eeya I get just an html page with styling and      <body ondblclick="var

Comment: Are you using a cPanel Manager to access your [shared ftp hosting]?

Comment: You can probably find more details about the error in your log files in the storage/logs folder.

Comment: @eeya no I dont.

Comment: @SimonSvensson I dont see anything related to that in the logs

Comment: If you are using shared host it happens mostly because of directory permission or your .htaccess setup. By the way, did you run php artisan storage:link or made it manually?

Comment: @train_fox I ran that command in my localhost and then uploaded files.

Comment: Yes it is because of your storage link. You should make it on server side again.

Comment: @train_fox how can I run the command in the hosting?

Comment: Probably you can't. Try to use your file manager to make a it on your public directory.

Comment: @train_fox is there a way I can link my development to storage/public so i can edit my fileS?

Comment: This reference might help: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9561/29/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-in-cpanel. Make sure you've setup your [Symlink] options [on] in your web server

Comment: Yes you can. But i suggest call your host support team. They should make the link as you wish for you.

Comment: You're using a user's name in the filename / URL. If a user can change their name, it's going to break your image links...

Comment: @Rob user can't change their name. it's their first name

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it.

I made a helper function, to get the file in the correct path:

```
function showProfile(){
  $path = storage_path('app/public/avatars/user_id_'.Auth::user()->id.'_'.Auth::user()->first_name.'/'.Auth::user()->avatar);

  if (!\File::exists($path)) {
      $path = storage_path('app/public/avatars/avatar.png');
      $file = \File::get($path);
  }

  $file = \File::get($path);

  return $file;
}
```

And then in my blade I used this:

```
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ base64_encode(showProfile()) }}" width="150px" alt="User Image">
```

I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but it works so far.